# Is there any InputStream Flushable class in Java?

Tags: java, inputstream, flush

I am using FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to read/write to a serial port.
I am sending commands to and receiving from a serial port. There will be data received by the serial port in between the next write command to serial which is unwanted and I want to flush it before reading. FileInputStream is not Flushable. Is there any InputStream Flushable class in Java?

Comment: read all the data and do nothing of it, tadaa! you just flush your input stream!

Comment: What does it mean to flush an input stream? For an output stream, it means to make sure that everything you've asked to write has been written. For an input stream, does it mean.... read everything until there is nothing more available? If so, just read until `available() == 0`.

Comment: What i want here is like tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH) which discards data received but not read so that before giving command to port I can discard any received data which is not read yet(unwanted) and get the disired response to command.

Comment: Answer: No, there is no "flush" command. To "flush", you must read and discard, as [explained by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724696/is-there-any-inputstream-flushable-class-in-java#comment88457925_50724696).